# Why IDN domains are not shown properly in Safari?

Tags: safari

For example `https://почивнидни.com` is shown as `https://xn--b1aekbb1acci5f.com` in Safari. There is no problem in Firefox, Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge.

Also `https://детскиградини.бг` is shown properly in Safari.

Is there any way to show `https://почивнидни.com` properly in Safari?